# How to alter database hour and date in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, date

How can I alter the date and hour of the database? I don't want to alter the hour and date from the server, only in database.

Comment: Are you trying to set the value to a static value?

Comment: I my searches I found the parameter fixed_date but isn't this that I want. I am looking for some parameter that I can set the date and hour only in the instance or database (not in linux server for example) and can't be fixed

Comment: perhaps it would help if you explained your _business_ problem instead of your preconceived technical solution . . .

Comment: Actually I'm studying for Oracle exam and in the exam has the topic Managing Data in Different Time Zones and because this I'm looking for some parameter to do some personal tests. isn't  business problem but I guess that can help some day

Comment: I assume you like to change the database time zone (aka `DBTIMEZONE`) - however most likely it will not bring the effect you would expect, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database/29272926#29272926

Comment: Like said, I'm not sure changing the database will do what you want. Dealing with time zones has two very different aspects: (1) One is the ability to store date and times in different time zones (or without any time zone), or in UTC. For that, create a table with multiple date/time columns reflecting those cases. (2) The other is the ability to connect clients that are in different time zones and have those see the data  expressed in the proper time zone: their local time zone, the time-zone of the original timestamp, or in UTC.

Comment: There is actually a third aspect: controlling the proper automatic changing of the timezone (from/to DST) depending on the time zone set for the database, and also the occasional updating of time zones and DST switching. So at the end, much depends on what sort of exam you are preparing for: a DBA exam or a developer exam ?

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind, I think it is a very poor design to create a table with multiple date/time columns reflecting those cases. Use only one single column and provide all cases by the client, views or virtual columns.

Comment: Well the idea is to have multiple columns with different data types: DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE, etc and compare the effect on the same  date/time value in different contexts: access from different clients in different time zones, observing the effect of taking the database to a different time zone, observing the effect of switching between winter and summer time, etc

Comment: If you have access from different clients in different time zones then `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` might be the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

[ALTER DATABASE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-DATABASE.html)

[set_time_zone_clause::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-DATABASE.html#GUID-8069872F-E680-4511-ADD8-A4E30AF67986__I2208406)

[image]

> **set_time_zone_clause**
>
> This clause has the same semantics in CREATE DATABASE and ALTER
>   DATABASE statements. When used in with ALTER DATABASE, this clause
>   resets the time zone of the database. To determine the time zone of
>   the database, query the built-in function DBTIMEZONE. After setting or
>   changing the time zone with this clause, you must restart the database
>   for the new time zone to take effect.
>
> Oracle Database normalizes all new TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE data
>   to the time zone of the database when the data is stored on
>   disk.Oracle Database does not automatically update existing data in
>   the database to the new time zone. Therefore, you cannot reset the
>   database time zone if there is any TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE data
>   in the database. You must first delete or export the TIMESTAMP WITH
>   LOCAL TIME ZONE data and then reset the database time zone. For this
>   reason, Oracle does not encourage you to change the time zone of a
>   database that contains data.
>
> For a full description of this clause, refer to set_time_zone_clause
>   in the documentation on CREATE DATABASE.

```
SQL> select dbtimezone from dual;

DBTIME
------
+02:00

SQL> ALTER DATABASE SET TIME_ZONE = '-05:00';

Database altered.

SQL> select dbtimezone from dual;

DBTIME
------
+02:00

SQL> startup force
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  536868920 bytes
Fixed Size                  8898616 bytes
Variable Size             226492416 bytes
Database Buffers          293601280 bytes
Redo Buffers                7876608 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> select dbtimezone from dual;

DBTIME
------
-05:00
```